# Is there anyway to check whether the user have access to a printer?

Tags: vb.net, printing, status, printers

The application I created sends the print to a network printer. If the user do not have access to particular printer then my application should throw an error message to the user.

Is there any way to check whether the user have access to particular network printer?

Answer (score 2):

i think you should check [PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and [PrintingPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printingpermission?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

above two should do for you

Comment: @CSS: if your issue is solved by above answer then marked it as solved